# Display Crash Issue During Ubuntu 20.04 Installation on Lenovo P360 with Nvidia T1000

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display

I am in need of some assistance with installing Ubuntu 20.04.5 server on my Lenovo P360 workstation with an Nvidia T1000 graphics card. I have encountered a problem that only appears with Ubuntu 20.04 (versions 20.04.5 and 20.04.6 specifically). For reference, Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 install without issue and handle the graphics just fine.

During the Ubuntu 20.04 installation, the display crashes in such a way that the pixels are randomly shifted, making it impossible to read anything.

[image]

Graphical output is only available on the first mini Display Port that is connected to the graphics card. Despite the visual issues, the installation logs and commands are fine, and I can manage to navigate the installer based on the crashed display. For example, an orange blur appears during installation, which helps to identify the process's current step, allowing blind navigation through the installer sequence. I managed to install Ubuntu 20.04.6 this way successfully. However, after the installation, the display crash persists.

A workaround I found is to disable the graphics card in the BIOS and use the integrated graphics during installation, requiring connection to a regular Display Port. After installation and configuration, I re-enabled the graphics card, and while the display still didn't work, I could connect via SSH, and everything else worked smoothly.

My question is, how can I resolve this issue so I can utilize the graphics on my Lenovo workstation with Ubuntu 20.04?

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance.